# Silverlight app storing data in a local sql express database

Tags: sql, sql-server, silverlight, xaml

I have built a simple silverlight app that stores the webcam captured images to the filesystem, my requirement is to store them locally in a sql server database located on a tablet so they can now or later be uploaded to a server when the network is available, this program needs to work offline. I have found the code for most of the application except the part that stores information and images to the database. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm using the new ComToolkit.Data.AdoConnection

Comment: Have you looked at using EntityFramework? It is Microsoft's preferred data access layer.